# SSH'ing with force pseudo-tty allocation doesn't print my MOTD

Tags: ssh, tty

I know that `-t` option in ssh allocate pseudo-tty. I'm using `-t` to "jump" to different directory on login, something like this:
`ssh -t my-server "cd /path/to/my/directory; bash --login"`.

Why if I log in without it (normally) `/etc/motd` is printed and with `-t` it is not? I know I can `cat /etc/motd` before `cd` but wondering is there cleaner solution and WHY is happening like that at all.

ps: As You can imagine I want MOTD to be prited on login even if I use `-t`.

Comment: weird. Is it really important?

Answer (score 0):

The MOTD is typicaLLY displayed by `login`, not `bash`,  so if you don't run `login` you don't get MOTD.  `sshd` probably doe not even use `login`, but does print `motd` depending on the setting of several of its flags. (as noted by Jakuje ) The way you are connecting through sshd does not trigger the motd behavior.

I suspect that trying to get things to run the way you want is going to be altering your profile file to do MOTD when bash is started by sshd.  I suppose you can check to see if `$tty` is defined, but there will probably still be games to keep you from getting two MOTD on a real login.

It really seems like a lot of effort for little gain.

Or, if you like

`ssh -t my-server "cd /path/to/my/directory; cat /etc/motd; bash --login"`

Comment: Nope. Motd is print during the [session initialization in `sshd`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/session.c#L930).

Comment: according to `man motd` it is  emitted by `login(1)`  I corrected my answer.

Comment: Yes, but `ssh(1)` is not running `login(1)`, unless you are using `UseLogin Yes` option in `sshd_config` (which is not advisable).

Comment: damn github's scripts slow my access down too much